# How to remove/disable specific sounds from the .FSB files?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know is not a wise idea to play LoL in windows XP, but its all I have and after shutting down some processes and lowering graphics I got a steady 15-30 fps (which is fine for me).

However, I noticed some sounds freeze my game for 0.3 seconds the first time they are played (e.g Sona spells), and late-game, when many explosions and things are going on, I simply can't play with the sound enabled.

This problem is gone when I [disable **all** sounds](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=2167343), but I really need to hear pings and turrets attacking me.

I need to know how to mess around with `.FSB` files, also I am open to alternative solutions to my problem, maybe there is a line I can add to `game.cfg` or something.

**edit:** I just downloaded a program *fsbext* and I managed to extract sound effects, my theories were right, Sona stuff is the heaviest (e.g `sona_hymnofvalor_melody_5` is 370KB), I will now find a way to create a .FSB from these sounds but overwriting the heavy ones with `Ahri.ultimateeffort2` which is only 4KB

Comment: If you are playing on an old desktop try getting a new sound card. That will decrease lag from sounds. What kind of machine do you have?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. download the program 'fsbext'
2. move it to `C:\FSbext`
3. go to `C:\LeagueOfLegends\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_game_client_en_us\managedfiles`
4. locate the latest version (you can sort by recently-modified for this)
5. then go to `...\Data\Sounds`
6. backup `LoL_Audio_en_US.fev` and `VOBank_en_US.fsb`
7. create a copy of `LoL_Audio_en_US.fev` and `VOBank_en_US.fsb` at `C:\FSbext`
8. run CMD
9. in CMD, type:

   - `cd..`
10. repeat #9 until you are at "C:\"
11. in CMD, type:

    - `cd FSbext` (you should now be at "C:\FSbext" after this)
12. (**Warning:** around 6.5k tiny files will extract after this in `C:\FSbext`) in CMD, type:

    - `fsbext -s build.dat VOBank_en_US.fsb`
13. (edit the sounds, overwrite the heavy ones, etc) **Note:** I try to only overwrite 'mono' with 'mono', 'stereo' with 'stereo', etc, as I am not sure what will happen if you replace one with a different one.
14. I noticed fsbext fail to extract `Interactive3DReturningToBase._10` correctly, **To Fix This:** manually rename `Interactive3DReturningToBase._10` to `Interactive3DReturningToBase._10.mp3`. And open the 'build.dat' we created (`C:\FSbext\build.dat`) with a text editor and search for `Interactive3DReturningToBase._10`, the first result will be the header, do *NOT* change that one, keep reading until you find the second `Interactive3DReturningToBase._10`, then change it to `Interactive3DReturningToBase._10.mp3`
15. (if you closed CMD, repeat the steps #8 to #11) in CMD, type:

    - `fsbext -s build.dat -r new.fsb`
16. rename `new.fsb` to `VOBank_en_US.fsb`
17. overwrite the old `VOBank_en_US.fsb` with the new one in the LoL dir

Comment: instead of repeating `cd..`, you can also just type `cd \\`, which returns you to the root directory.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness It's interesting how fast people forget to remember how DOS works. It's just been... wait, what? 15 years since Win98? Really? D*mn, i'm getting old :(